# How to make your text "use cookies"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to make your text "use cookies"?

I have a react application, I want to warn users that I use cookies, how to make a frame with the text where it says **“We use cookies”?**

```js
    useEffect(() => {
     alert(document.cookies)
    })
```

Comment: `alert()` creates a blocking popup window, which is definitely not the way to go. You'll want to build an html component with the text "We use cookies".

Comment: Do you want to use an alert that dimisses on tapping anywhere on the screen or so?